# How do I create an Extent Report in C# when running BDD tests in Parallel with Specflow

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, extentreports

When I run C# Specflow tests singularly my Extent Report is generated correctly.

However, when I run the tests in Parallel the Extent Report is wrong. Steps get written to the wrong Scenarios and Scenarios from the same Feature are not grouped.

Has anyone managed to generate an ExtentReport correctly when running tests in parallel using C# and Specflow?

Below is the code I am currently using.

Thanks for any help.

```
using AutomationFramework.Base;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using AutomationFramework.Helpers;
using AutomationFramework.Config;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Gherkin.Model;

namespace EmployeeTest.Hooks
{

[Binding]
public class HookInitialize : TestInitializeHook
{

    private readonly ParallelConfig _parallelConfig;
    private readonly FeatureContext _featureContext;
    private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public HookInitialize(ParallelConfig parallelConfig, FeatureContext featureContext, ScenarioContext scenarioContext) : base(parallelConfig)
    {
        _parallelConfig = parallelConfig;
        _featureContext = featureContext;
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    private static ExtentTest featureName;
    private static ExtentTest scenario;
    private static ExtentReports extent;


    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void TestInitalize()
    {
        //Initialize the Report
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\Logs\ExtentReport.html");
        htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;
        htmlReporter.Config.ReportName = "Automation Test Report";
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

    }


    [AfterStep]
    public void InsertReportingSteps()
    {
        var stepType = _scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();


        if (_scenarioContext.TestError == null)
        {
            if (stepType == "Given")
                scenario.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
            else if (stepType == "When")
                scenario.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
            else if (stepType == "Then")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
            else if (stepType == "And")
                scenario.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
        }
        else if (_scenarioContext.TestError != null)
        {
            if (stepType == "Given")
            {
                scenario.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.InnerException);
                ScreenShotHelpers.CaptureScreen(_parallelConfig.Driver, _featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
            }
            else if (stepType == "When")
            {
                scenario.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.InnerException);
                ScreenShotHelpers.CaptureScreen(_parallelConfig.Driver, _featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
            }
            else if (stepType == "Then")
            {
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message);
                ScreenShotHelpers.CaptureScreen(_parallelConfig.Driver, _featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
            }
        }



    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        InitializeSettings();
        Settings.ApplicationCon = Settings.ApplicationCon.DBConnect(Settings.AppConnectionString);

        //Create feature name
        featureName = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(_featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);

        //Get scenario name
        scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);

    }


    [AfterScenario]
    public void TestStop()
    {
        _parallelConfig.Driver.Quit();

    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void TearDownReport()
    {
        //Write the report to the report directory
        extent.Flush();


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I was exactly trying the same thing. Here is the quick fix

Use [ThreadStatic] attribute to your scenario variable. It gives you the thread specific variable.

```
 [ThreadStatic]
 private static ExtentTest scenario;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Version of tools used for Parallel execution using Specflow, NUnit, Extent Report**

1. Extent Report - 4.1.0
2. NUnit - 3.13.1
3. Specflow.NUnit - 3.9.22

Complete Code (Hooks.cs) is as follows:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.Specflow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Gherkin.Model;
using NUnit.Framework;

[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]

namespace TeamNameTestScripts.Hooks
{
[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    static string configTheme = "standard";
    static string configReportPath = @$"C:\AutomationResults\ExtentReport.html";



    [ThreadStatic]
    private static ExtentTest feature;
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static ExtentTest scenario;
    private static ExtentReports extentReport;
    private static readonly string base64ImageType = "base64";

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void InitializeReport()
    {
        //Initialize Extent report before test starts
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(configReportPath);

        switch (configTheme.ToLower())
        {
            case "dark":
                htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;
                break;
            case "standard":
            default:
                htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
                break;
        }

        //Attach report to reporter
        extentReport = new ExtentReports();
        extentReport.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void TearDownReport()
    {
        extentReport.Flush();
    }

    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void BeforeFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        feature = extentReport.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InitializeScenario(FeatureContext featureContext, ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        scenario = feature.CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void CleanUp(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        //to check if we missed to implement any step
        string resultOfImplementation = scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString();

        //Pending Status
        if (resultOfImplementation == "UndefinedStep")
        {
            // Log.StepNotDefined();
        }
    }

    [AfterStep]
    public void InsertReportingSteps(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        string stepType = scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();
        string stepInfo = scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text;


        //to check if we missed to implement steps inside method
        string resultOfImplementation = scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString();


        if (scenarioContext.TestError == null && resultOfImplementation == "OK")
        {
            if (stepType == "Given")
                scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepInfo);
            else if (stepType == "When")
                scenario.CreateNode<When>(stepInfo);
            else if (stepType == "Then")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo);
            else if (stepType == "And")
                scenario.CreateNode<And>(stepInfo);
            else if (stepType == "But")
                scenario.CreateNode<And>(stepInfo);
        }
        else if (scenarioContext.TestError != null)
        {
            Exception? innerException = scenarioContext.TestError.InnerException;
            string? testError = scenarioContext.TestError.Message;

            if (stepType == "Given")
                scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepInfo).Fail(innerException, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "When")
                scenario.CreateNode<When>(stepInfo).Fail(innerException, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "Then")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo).Fail(testError, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "And")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo).Fail(testError, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "But")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo).Fail(testError, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());

        }
        else if (resultOfImplementation == "StepDefinitionPending")
        {
            string errorMessage = "Step Definition is not implemented!";

            if (stepType == "Given")
                scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepInfo).Fail(errorMessage, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "When")
                scenario.CreateNode<When>(stepInfo).Fail(errorMessage, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "Then")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo).Fail(errorMessage, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());
            else if (stepType == "But")
                scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepInfo).Fail(errorMessage, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64ImageType).Build());

        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides making

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static ExtentTest scenario;
```

Please use a dictionary to store and create `ExentTest` Accordingly in `[BeforeFeature]` and attach the respective scenarios to it in `[BeforeScenario]` when running Specflow BDD scripts in Parallel for Proper Kind of Extent Reports with Appropriate Formatting.

```
    private static ExtentTest featureName;
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ExtentTest> FeatureDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ExtentTest>();

    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void initializeDriver(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        featureName = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
        FeatureDictionary.TryAdd(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title, featureName);
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void SetUpTest(FeatureContext _featureContext)
    {
        string InBSName = _featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title;
        if (FeatureDictionary.ContainsKey(InBSName))
        {
            scenario = FeatureDictionary[InBSName].CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        }
    }
```